# Sending data to a fragment already created

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem here and would like to know if anyone can help me solve this.
I have a ViewPager, with 2 fragments, fragment A and fragment B.
This viewPager is inside a fragment, we will call FragmentMain.
FragmentMain contains a search, I need to send to fragment A and fragment B, which was typed in searchView, then inside fragment A and fragment B, I can "work" with text typed in searchView.
Thank you!
[i was try it's.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960380/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-already-created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot many ways or pattern to pass the data from fragment to fragment, I will list top two ways in the order of preference for cleaner & testable code:

- you can use Otto as a event bus http://square.github.com/otto/
- [Define an Interface](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface)

---

**UPDATE** Otto is officially deprecated, however you can continue using it, As alternative use [this](http://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/)

Comment: Don't use Otto, it is deprecated. There is no development happening on it. You can use RxEventBus. Have a look at https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba