# Pass RecyclerView item position of Fragment One to another RecyclerView Adapter of Fragment Two

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have set `Recyclerview` in `Fragment` one.I want to send  position of RecyclerView item from RecyclerView Adapter of Fragment one to RecyclerView Adapter of Fragment Two to set particular item of RecyclerView in Fragment two.
This is code for Fragment one Adapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           final CurrentStatusEntry current=filterList.get(position);
          // holder.number.setText(current.getNo());
           holder.Name.setText(current.getName());
           holder.People.setText(current.getPeople());
           holder.Time.setText(current.getTime());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position=holder.getAdapterPosition();

                    AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,satusInfo).addToBackStack("info").commit();
                }
            });
```

How to pass this position ?

Comment: U can pass data fragment with create Bundle and setArguments.

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("position", position);
statusInfo.setArguments(args);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960380/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-already-created

Comment: But how to receive that data in AdapterClass of Second Fragment.

Comment: you mave have to look at this post.
[pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: With this I am able to get the Value in Another Fragment.But the adapter   position is set from Adapter Class so how to access the value in adapter class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bundle` for this try like below example :

In Fragment one `setArguments` :

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In second Fragment `getArguments` :

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Refer Android [Doc.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Answer (score 0):

In fragment one post fragment instance to fragment two

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.ftHolder, fragmentTwo.newInstance(getAdapterPosition()))
                                .addToBackStack("info")
                                .commit();
```

in fragment two add this function

```
public static fragmentTwo newInstance(int position) {
    fragmentTwo fragment = new fragmentTwo();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putInt("position", position);
    fragment.setArguments(bdl);
    return fragment;
}
```

And in onCreate() or onActivityCreated() get it and use it anywhere

```
position = getArguments().getInt("position");
```