# Pass data from Activity to Fragment that is already displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

How do you pass a data from activity to fragment that's already active? I can transfer using a bundle but the only way I can get it is using `createView` on that fragment but my problem is it is already created. Is there anyway that I can pass data from activity to fragment and then call that data without using `onCreateView`

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960380/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-already-created) to get what I needed but the data is not accessible due to static

Comment: via callback interface, look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

Comment: You should look at event bus in my answer. The easiest solution, I found ever.

Comment: @Khemraj sure currently reading on it and also plus 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If view is already created then onCreateview will not call so you can pass data via **BroadcastReceiver**

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiverUpdateDownload = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Getdata from intent
        }
    };
```

Regester your BroadcastReceiver in onCreateView

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("STRING_ID_FOR_BRODCAST");
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiverUpdateDownload, filter);
```

unregister your Receiver at onStop

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (receiverUpdateDownload != null) {
        try {
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiverUpdateDownload);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Call your brodcast from acttvity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("STRING_ID_FOR_BRODCAST");
 intent.putExtra("key","value");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: what code should i put on activity and in the fragment?

Comment: You need to put BroadcastReceiver in your fragment, just put sendBrodcast (last code in ans) in activity, it will trigger your BroadcastReceiver whenever you call 
`Intent intent = new Intent("STRING_ID_FOR_BRODCAST");`

Comment: already done but how can i get the data? like passing it to toast?

Comment: no pass data via intent like
`intent.putExtra("key","1");` here i pass value 1
after you will get data in onReceive like
`Bundle b = intent.getExtras()
String a =  b.getString("Key")` you will Receive 1 in String a

Comment: and that what you awesomeness in every bite hahahah TYSM :D

Comment: I need a Kotlin answer.

Comment: what should i do if i want to send data from activity to fragment?

Comment: @masoudmjm You can create fragment object in activity and create public method with parameter in fragment (if fragment is already created) otherwise you can create fragment Instance for passing data

Answer (score 3):

There can be multiple ways

- Get Fragment instance by using **`findFragmentById`** as **@Belbahar Raouf** showed.
- Use **`BroadcastReceiver`** to send data between `Activity`, `Fragment` or `Service`. It works everywhere. But it can be little lengthy.
- You can use **[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)**, a great invention from GreenBot. **Just one line to pass data.**

  `EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());`

See [Event bus documentation](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for implementation.

#### Make a model class that will be passed `MessageEvent.java`.

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

#### Subscribe your listener in `Fragment`.

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

#### Register & Unregister event bus with **`Fragment Lifecycle`**.

```
@Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

#### From your `Activity`, just fire event, this will be received by `Fragment`.

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Before that add dependency to your gradle.

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

#### Best thing of EventBus-

> It works in `Activity`, `Fragment` & `Services`. You need not to make
>   multiple broadcast receiver with multiple intent types. Just post event in 
>   one line code.

#### I also use EventBus for ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation :

> The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the
>   Fragment instance with findFragmentById(), then directly call the
>   fragment's public methods.

Example (declare this in your activity):

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
           getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available
            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        }
```

And in your fragment implement the method that will do the trick.

Comment: Yes, this is the fragment to which you want to sens data.

Comment: i dont know but when I write it. it turns red. although it is existing